# Xbox 360 S starting but not working

Tags: xbox-360

When I turn on the Xbox, it works fine until it tries to load the profiles. I get the starting animation and sound, but the screen shows a non-moving loading sign. Has anyone experienced the same thing, know what's wrong, and/or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Try moving around the main menu (even though it's not displaying). Does it make sounds as if it's working with no visual?

Comment: Hold Y and the left trigger while turning it on. It will reset it's display and make it run quicker.

Comment: I agree with the HDD though. Try removing it. Put a USB in if you need extra space.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar, turned out to be a faulty hard drive. I removed the extra 250 GB one, and it worked fine with the internal 4 GB one. The hdd was not repairable, so all my save games were lost. Yay for cloud saves, wish I used them.